# Correct interpretation of genitive plural noun when preceded by another plural noun

Tags: грамматика, падежи

Which is the correct translation of **учитель увидел по глазам учеников, что что-то случилось**?

1. The teacher saw in the **eyes** of the **student**, that something had happened.
2. The teacher saw in the **eyes** of the **students**, that something had happened.

I understand that **учеников** is in the genitive plural, but I'm confused whether it's plural due to more than one eye (**глазам**) or because there is more than one student.

Comment: The second option is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Dmitry said, the second option is correct. If you translate first expression to russian it will be **учитель увидел по глазам ученика, что что-то случилось**. And it has nothing to do with eyes, i think in english it would sound as awkward as in russian if you say something like 'The teacher saw in the **eye** of the **students**, that something had happened' :D